# How to remove data fields having same id based on the date

Tags: sql-server

How to remove data fields having the same id based on the date.
my table is like :

```
id   subject       date
1    MCA           2/5/2010
1    BSC SCIENCE   5/8/1997
2    BTECH         8/9/1999
3    BTECH         8/6/2000
3    MTECH         6/7/2014
```

HOW CAN I GET THE OUTPUT LIKE :

```
id   subject       date
1    MCA           2/5/2010
2    BTECH         8/9/1999
3    MTECH         6/7/2014
```

Comment: based on date? seems descending in your output result, true?

Comment: based on the latest date of each id @ibubi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `Where` clause as next logic :-

```
 where MyTable.date < (select max(t2.date) from MyTable t2 where t2.id = MyTable.id)
```

**Demo**

```
Create database TestDB
Go
use TestDB
Go
Create table MyTable (id int , [subject] varchar(20), [date] date)
go
Insert into MyTable values (1, 'MCA', '2/5/2010')
Insert into MyTable values (1, ' BSC SCIENCE', '5/8/1997')
Insert into MyTable values (2, 'BTECH', '8/9/1999')
Insert into MyTable values (3, 'BTECH', ' 8/6/2000')
Insert into MyTable values (3, 'MTECH', '6/7/2014')
go
select * from MyTable
```

**Results before Delete:-**

```
1   MCA             2010-02-05
1   BSC SCIENCE 1997-05-08
2   BTECH           1999-08-09
3   BTECH           2000-08-06
3   MTECH            2014-06-07
```

Then Use the next Delete Statement:-

```
delete from MyTable
    where MyTable.date < (select max(t2.date) from MyTable t2 where t2.id = MyTable.id)

select * from MyTable
```

**The Result after Delete:-**

```
1   MCA     2010-02-05
2   BTECH   1999-08-09
3   MTECH   2014-06-07
```

Answer (score 2):

```
With CTE AS (
    SElECT ID, Subject,date, RoW_NUMBER() OVER(
        PARTITION BY ID 
        order by date desc
    ) rn 
    from TableName
)
SELECT ID,Subject, Date FROM CTE 
WHERE RN = 1;
```

Comment: I would do it slightly different - to preserve default ordering, I would write `order by (select NULL)`.

Comment: if you use "order by (select null) " then you get different output

Comment: That is what I mean - you preserve default ordering of table :) But to be clear - there's nothing wrong with your answer, it was just small remark, which OP might find helpful.